# Hibernate sets and many to many index column issue

Tags: java, hibernate

all. I had the following code.

```
  @ManyToMany(targetEntity = com.acs.gs.juror.model.security.SecurityGroup.class, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
  @JoinTable(name = "REP_DSGN_SEC_GRP_LNK", 
      joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "REPORT_DESIGN_UUID", referencedColumnName = "UUID")}, 
      inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "SECURITY_GROUP_UUID", referencedColumnName = "UUID")})
  @IndexColumn(name="HIBERNATE_IDX")
  private List<SecurityGroup> groups;
```

Which one day started having a multiple bag issue. So I fixed it by changing it to a set, thus:

```
  @ManyToMany(targetEntity = com.acs.gs.juror.model.security.SecurityGroup.class, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
  @JoinTable(name = "REP_DSGN_SEC_GRP_LNK", 
      joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "REPORT_DESIGN_UUID", referencedColumnName = "UUID")}, 
      inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "SECURITY_GROUP_UUID", referencedColumnName = "UUID")})
  @IndexColumn(name="HIBERNATE_IDX")
  private Set<SecurityGroup> groups;
```

This works fine until I run my data loader and get the following error:

```
[java] Exception in thread "main" com.acs.gs.juror.dao.FailedInsertException: Unable to save object:ALTF Funds By Case|ALTF Funds By Case Report|java.util.GregorianCalendar[time=18000000,areFieldsSet=true,areAllFieldsSet=true,lenient=true,zone=sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfo[id="America/New_York",offset=-18000000,dstSavings=3600000,useDaylight=true,transitions=235,lastRule=java.util.SimpleTimeZone[id=America/New_York,offset=-18000000,dstSavings=3600000,useDaylight=true,startYear=0,startMode=3,startMonth=2,startDay=8,startDayOfWeek=1,startTime=7200000,startTimeMode=0,endMode=3,endMonth=10,endDay=1,endDayOfWeek=1,endTime=7200000,endTimeMode=0]],firstDayOfWeek=1,minimalDaysInFirstWeek=1,ERA=1,YEAR=1970,MONTH=0,WEEK_OF_YEAR=1,WEEK_OF_MONTH=1,DAY_OF_MONTH=1,DAY_OF_YEAR=1,DAY_OF_WEEK=5,DAY_OF_WEEK_IN_MONTH=1,AM_PM=0,HOUR=0,HOUR_OF_DAY=0,MINUTE=0,SECOND=0,MILLISECOND=0,ZONE_OFFSET=-18000000,DST_OFFSET=0]|null|ALTFFundsByCase||PDF|[]|Lexptrain|Lexptrain|314||REPORTING|OUTPUT_TYPE|Browser|Browser|Jan 1, 1970 12:00:00 AM||null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|
[java]  at com.acs.gs.juror.dao.hibernate.HibernateDAO.create(HibernateDAO.java:65)
[java]  at com.acs.gs.juror.dataload.cs.maricopa.LoadReportDesigns.loadData(LoadReportDesigns.java:116)
[java]  at com.acs.gs.juror.dataload.cs.maricopa.SeedDataLoader.loadData(SeedDataLoader.java:48)
[java]  at com.acs.gs.juror.dataload.cs.maricopa.SeedDataLoader.main(SeedDataLoader.java:18)
[java] Caused by: org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: Could not execute JDBC batch update; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: Could not execute JDBC batch update
[java]  at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.SessionFactoryUtils.convertHibernateAccessException(SessionFactoryUtils.java:636)
[java]  at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateAccessor.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateAccessor.java:412)
[java]  at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.doExecute(HibernateTemplate.java:424)
[java]  at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.executeWithNativeSession(HibernateTemplate.java:374)
[java]  at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.save(HibernateTemplate.java:694)
[java]  at com.acs.gs.juror.dao.hibernate.HibernateDAO.create(HibernateDAO.java:62)
[java]  ... 3 more
[java] Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: Could not execute JDBC batch update
[java]  at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:94)
[java]  at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:66)
[java]  at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.executeBatch(AbstractBatcher.java:275)
[java]  at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:266)
[java]  at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:171)
[java]  at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:321)
[java]  at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:50)
[java]  at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1027)
[java]  at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateAccessor.flushIfNecessary(HibernateAccessor.java:390)
[java]  at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.doExecute(HibernateTemplate.java:420)
[java]  ... 6 more
[java] Caused by: java.sql.BatchUpdateException: Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'HIBERNATE_IDX', table 'agilejury-thehl_MC.dbo.REP_DSGN_SEC_GRP_LNK'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.
[java]  at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.JtdsStatement.executeBatch(JtdsStatement.java:947)
[java]  at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyPreparedStatement.executeBatch(NewProxyPreparedStatement.java:1723)
[java]  at org.hibernate.jdbc.BatchingBatcher.doExecuteBatch(BatchingBatcher.java:70)
[java]  at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.executeBatch(AbstractBatcher.java:268)
[java]  ... 13 more
```

I have tried deleting the @IndexColumn entry to no avail. Hibernate creates the column regardless. If hibernate creates it without me mapping it, I don't have a way to store a value in it, so how can it be having a problem with it being null?

I'm kinda stuck at this point and have no idea how to proceed.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure that at the time of persisting you have initialized field for `HIBERNATE_IDX` in `SecurityGroup`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like this is another Hibernate black box issue that no one really understands. I ended up just creating my own entity instead of a join stable and that fixed the issue.

Answer (score 1):

As the error clearly indicates .

> Caused by: java.sql.BatchUpdateException: Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'HIBERNATE_IDX', table 'agilejury-thehl_MC.dbo.REP_DSGN_SEC_GRP_LNK'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.

Which says one of your elements of `SecurityGroup` type in the `groups` collection have `HIBERNATE_IDX` field defined as `null`. You should look for initialization of this element when an element is added to the `groups`.

Answer (score 0):

Show us the create table statement for the `REP_DSGN_SEC_GRP_LNK` table and I will show you where your null restriction is.  Take out the null restriction and it won't complain about it being a null.  The drawback is you will be cramming nulls into something that shouldn't be null.

Your `List` does not allow nulls, which is protecting you from this problem.  You changed it to `Set`, which allows nulls.  So a few options:

1. Fix your data in your Set to not have nulls.
2. Loosen the restriction on nulls.